# Touch ID API response is very slow in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10, touch-id

I am using `Touch ID` feature in my app, it was working flawlessly in `iOS 9` but it does not perform well in the recently released `iOS 10` version.

It takes at least 1 or 2 seconds to show **Touch ID for "App Name"** alert. Initially I assumed that the problem exists only in my app then I tested `Touch ID` feature in the **Apple Notes** app even this one also has same issue. Is there any work around to fix this?

**Code**

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
        context.localizedFallbackTitle = @"Enter Passcode";
[context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                localizedReason:reason
                          reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                  if (completionBlock) {
                                      completionBlock(success,error);
                                  }
                              });
                          }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing this on another app as well; then chances are there is no workaround for it that *you* can do. Apple themselves will need to sort the issue out. Perhaps file a radar, with a test project to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed the same problem in my app. It seems to be fixed in iOS version 10.0.2!